# filter an HTML-elements filled array (javascript)

Tags: javascript, dom

i have two arrays that both contains HTML Elements, i want to remove from the first array all the elements that are also present in the second one.

```js
var a = [document.createElement('div'), document.createElement('span')],
    b = [document.createElement('span'), document.createElement('p')];

filter(a,b) == [document.createElement('span')] // true
```

i tried with something like this, but it seems like it doesn't work:

```js
var filter = function(a,b) {
   return a.filter(element => {
      return b.map(element_ => {
         return element.isEqualNode(element_);
      }).includes(false);
   });
}
```

Comment: `a.filter(element => !b.includes(element));`

Comment: @Tigger no, because i think that with DOM HTML elements it is not possible to check the equality with ==

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let res = a.filter((el)=> { return b.find((el2)=> el.localName === el2.localName)});

// res = [span];
```

So, `el.localName` is a property of a HTML element of type string which contains the name of the element. Which can be used for comparing two HTML elements

> For Example: In Case of div its 'div'

Code returns the common element present in both the arrays.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: can you be more accurate explaining better how your code works?

Comment: @Giuppox let me know if it worked for you?

Comment: yeah! it works, thanks :). You know that in arrow functions, if there is only one parameter, you can remove the parenthesis?

Comment: Yes, Can I expect a upvote for my ans?